# Using Read() and Write() Functions to Concatenate 2 Files

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm currently learning how to use the read() and write() functions to implement a program which  concatenates files.

I'm concatenating a text file named "NotesBetweenTwoSisters2.txt" to the end of another text file named "NotesBetweenTwoSisters1.txt." (So now NotesBetweenTwoSisters1.txt has a larger file size.)

**"NotesBetweenTwoSisters1.txt"**

```
Madam, 

Keep an eye on the radar. If it doesn't look that good for kayak paddling tonight, then the next time which we can rent the kayak is tomorrow noon. 
But at that time you will have to take care of the pup, and only your darling and I can enjoy the trip. 

Sis
```

**"NotesBetweenTwoSisters2.txt"**

```
Hi sis,

I only deal with loyal ones. Obviously the pup is much more loyal. You and I really see eye to eye on this issue. Enjoy your kayak paddling.

"Your Madam"
```

I already wrote the code that has both of the file contents outputting on the terminal as expected, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the concatenation right. If anyone can help me out on how to use read() and write() functions correctly to concatenate files together, I would really appreciate it!

**Current Program Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream inFile1;
    fstream inFile2;
    fstream outFile;

    inFile1.open("NotesBetweenTwoSisters1.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);
    inFile2.open("NotesBetweenTwoSisters2.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);

    inFile1.seekg(0, inFile1.end);
    int size1 = inFile1.tellg();
    inFile1.seekg(0, inFile1.beg);

    // cout << "File #1 Size: " << size1 << endl;
    char arr1[size1];

    inFile1.read(arr1, sizeof(arr1));
    inFile1.close();

    inFile2.seekg(0, inFile2.end);
    int size2 = inFile2.tellg();
    inFile2.seekg(0, inFile2.beg);

    // cout << "File #2 Size: " << size2 << endl;
    char arr2[size2];

    inFile2.read(arr2, sizeof(arr2));
    inFile2.close();

    outFile.open("outputFile.dat", ios::out|ios::app|ios::binary);
    outFile.write(arr1, sizeof(arr1));
    outFile.write(arr2, sizeof(arr2));

    for(int count = 0; count < size1; count++)
    {
        cout << arr1[count] << "";
    }

    for(int count = 0; count < size2; count++)
    {
        cout << arr2[count] << "";
    }

    cout << endl;
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Current Output**

```
Madam,

Keep an eye on the radar. If it doesn't look that good for kayak paddling tonight, then the next time which we can rent the kayak is tomorrow noon.
But at that time you will have to take care of the pup, and only your darling and I can enjoy the trip.

Sis
Hi sis,

I only deal with loyal ones. Obviously the pup is much more loyal. You and I really see eye to eye on this issue. Enjoy your kayak paddling.

"Your Madam"
```

Comment: you did it wrong. in case of concatenation, you just need one output file logically and save both texts inside that one file. But what you doing here is opening to different files as output and write each of the opened text file to different output texxt file.

Comment: I noticed that too. Can you provide me an example? @prhmma

Comment: replace `outFile2` with `outFile1`. and open it just once. it will write at the end of the file

Comment: I updated my code based on your input. Let me know what you think. @prhmma

Comment: yes, it will work with few changes. I will provide you with an answer in details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you need to use `vector` or you have to define dynamic arrays syntactically right. this is how you define a dynamic array in C++:

```
char *arr1 = new char[size1]
char *arr2 = new char[size2]
```

since `size1` and `size2` are not constants and will be initialized in run time, you can not declare dynamic arrays like this `char arr1[size1]` you need pointer to an array that will be declared as above. also you can read more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).
then your `write` function will work as expected and append your two arrays in a binary file called `outfile`.

Comment: After I replaced both my original `char arr1[size1]` and `char arr2[size2]` with your dynamic arrays, I got this output: `Mada░ñ╢                                                                                                                                                                     

Hi└ ╢                                                 ╨P8w            ╨P8w            ╨P8w            ╨P8w            ╨P8w                              xACw        ╪`

Comment: that is right, since your output file is not text, it is binary. binary file can not be shown by text editors.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for you help!